# How to get correct authorization value from header to pass to jwt method?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am working with a mern application. For authentication I am using JWT tokens. The flow is that the middleware(a function) in every route checks if the user is authenticated or not. This is done by checking the authorization header. The code is as under:

```
    app.get("/comments", authenticateToken, postController.viewComments);
```

The function authenticateToken:

```
    function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
      authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
      jwt.verify(authHeader, "secretkey", (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json(authHeader); //I got to know from here that the format of the token 
                                         //changes for some reason
        console.log('works);  
        next();
      });
    }
```

The problem is when I console the authHeader I get correct output i.e "secretTokenValueHere". If I paste this token value directly in jwt.verify function, it works fine as well. However when I directly pass authHeader in the jwt.verify it throws error that the token is not valid. I consoled the token as well and the output I got was formatted as below:

```
   "\"secretTokenValueHere\""
```

I guess I am missing out a slight detail. Would be grateful if anyone could help. Also, I am testing all apis on postman. TIA

Comment: Why are you defining `authHeader` at a global scope? Can you try `JSON.parse(authHeader)` before passing it to `jwt.verify`?  The issue seems to be that `req.headers` is being escaped post parsing/sent from your client

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks a ton. Can you briefly explain why was parsing required in this case?

Comment: I don't have enough context, but it seems that your application(or UI) is escaping the String before sending it/and or that the receiving server is not parsing the headers. Can you put a breakpoint on your sender and see how the headers look like?